# function write(message) not working

Tags: javascript

I'm doing the PluralSight JavaScript Fundamentals course and he enters this code into the JavaScript window of jsbin (jsbin.com)

```
function write(message) {
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += message + '<br/>';
}

var streetNumber = 49;

var streetName = "Brunswick";

write(typeof streetNumber + " " + streetNumber);

write(typeof streetName + " " + streetName);
```

and when he Previews it writes out the types and values.  The video is a year old and now jsbin has a Render (not Preview) button.  When I enter the above code and Render I get a blank screen.

I tried pasting the code into an .html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<!--<meta charset=utf-8 />-->
<title>JS Test</title>

</head>
<body>
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
<script>
function write(message) {
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += message + '<br/>';
}

var streetNumber = 49;

var streetName = "Brunswick"';

write(typeof streetNumber + " " + streetNumber);

write(typeof streetName + " " + streetName);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and then opened the file in IE9, and the latest version of Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera (my OS is Win7 Ult).  They all display Hello World and nothing else.  I'm probably missing something really simple here, can someone help me out?

Comment: For one reson there is no element with id "message". So there is no where the text will be appended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a message element. Change the `#hello` element to `#message`.

```
<p id="hello">Hello World</p>
```

To this

```
<p id="message">Hello World</p>
```

This is what is needed for the `getElementById` code to have a place to print your output. Without an element having the requested ID, nothing will turn up, and hence nothing will be printed.

You have a syntax error as well:

```
/*                          v----- This little guy here doesn't belong. */
var streetName = "Brunswick"';
```

Note the umatched single quote at the end of this string. Remove that and you should be good to go:

Comment: Uh dah!!  I knew it was something simple.  You would think in a Fundamental course they would point that out (changing the id).  Also interesting how one little typo will make it fail completely.  Thanks